# How to filter Rails result set based on the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I want to create a restful API where a user can go to **foo.com/compani/users** and they will get a list of all users from that company.

My routes.rb file has:

```
resources :schools do
  resources :users
end
```

My models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :school
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users
end
```

However if i go to /schools/1/users I get ALL users for all schools (same list for 1, 2, 12314, etc). From what I understood I was supposed to get list of all users that have school_id of '1'. What am I missing?

Comment: Please `select id,school_id from users` (in sql) and show the results.

Comment: Added the (correct) controller and template, and it now works. I had it returning '@user' and then the template was iterating through @users, which of course it didn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you nested the rescources correctly  you should be able to do something like this:

```
Controller:

def index
   @users = School.find(1).users
end

View:

@users.each do |user|

user.name

end
```